# Simple Javascript Accordion

Tags: javascript, html

I have put together a simple Javascript accordion, though the Javascript code I think could possibly be slimmed down. I would welcome any feedback anyone has on what I have done, and any advice to improve.

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae at placeat nesciunt nostrum accusamus debitis fuga similique quisquam, rerum temporibus, quod asperiores nulla, eveniet libero earum eaque harum inventore minima ipsum saepe omnis. Officia, est, maiores. Reprehenderit odio perspiciatis voluptates commodi ex at praesentium laborum deleniti libero, architecto sit optio repellat est molestiae beatae, magnam qui voluptatibus. Ducimus mollitia dignissimos minus sapiente quidem, animi adipisci laboriosam aliquam asperiores facere. Repellat recusandae doloribus incidunt voluptatibus quibusdam rem delectus inventore nisi, laudantium. Doloribus eum vero, consequuntur nisi enim quam non odio dignissimos praesentium nostrum magnam consequatur totam reprehenderit quaerat. Saepe, blanditiis fugit?</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
div.accordion {
  .accordion-content {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 400ms;
    &.active {
      overflow: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  function toggle(){
    if (this.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('active')) {
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
      this.nextElementSibling.removeAttribute('style');
      this.classList.remove('active');
    }
    else {
      var elementHeight = this.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight;
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');
      this.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = elementHeight + 'px';
      this.classList.add('active');
    }
  }

  var accordion = document.querySelector('.js div.accordion');
  var header = accordion.getElementsByClassName('accordion-header');

  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
    header[i].addEventListener('click', toggle);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any issue with code other than below two things.

First, I'll suggest is to use [`classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) instead of contains and then add/remove class. See [browser compability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility) and if target browser does not support `toggle` method, use [polyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Polyfill).

```
function toggle() {
    if (this.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('active')) {
        this.nextElementSibling.removeAttribute('style');
    } else {
        var elementHeight = this.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight;
        this.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = elementHeight + 'px';
    }

    // Toggle `active` class
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
    this.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Second, caching the length of array when iterating using `for` will *slightly* improve the performance.

```
for (var i = 0, len = header.length; i < len; i++) {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                  : Caching length
```

---

If running the code in latest environment where [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) is supported, you can use it to iterate over elements.

```
var headers = accordion.getElementsByClassName('accordion-header');
for (header of headers) {
    header.addEventListener('click', toggle);
}
```

Comment: The for ... of loop might be an alternative